# Show JSON data in table with selectbox

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

I want to select every data with same key in json from selectbox. For example, I want to select all values ​​with "author" key by putting them in the selectbox.

In the same way, I want to select the values ​​corresponding to the "country" key by putting them in a selectbox.

**My JSON**

```
"kitap": [
  {
    "author": "Chinua Achebe",
    "country": "Nigeria",
    "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
    "language": "English",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
    "pages": 209,
    "title": "Things Fall Apart",
    "year": 1958
  },
  {
    "author": "Hans Christian Andersen",
    "country": "Denmark",
    "imageLink": "images/fairy-tales.jpg",
    "language": "Danish",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Tales_Told_for_Children._First_Collection.\n",
    "pages": 784,
    "title": "Fairy tales",
    "year": 1836
  }
]
}
```

**My javascript**

```
let table2 = document.getElementById("tr2")

var books = fetch("kitap.json")
.then(res=> res.json())
.then(veri => {for(let data in veri ) {
    for(deger of veri[data]) {

        table2.innerHTML+= `
            <td><select><option value="${deger.author}"></select></td>
            <td><select><option value="${deger.country}"></select></td>
            <td><select><option value="${deger.imageLink}"></select></td>
        `
    }
}})
```

how can i edit?

Comment: does anyone know?

Comment: Were you able to populate and display your table?  If so you just need to do the same thing to populate a `<select>` with `<option>`s, in fact you can probably populate them using the same initial fetch loop.  After that you need to write the code to re-populate the table once the user makes choices from the `select`'s.

Comment: now both author and country information are in the same selectbox, I didn't quite understand what you mean. Any chance to show it with code?

Answer (score 0):

So this is one approach. The code is untested but should provide enough information for you to get started.

```
let table2 = document.getElementById("tr2");
let select1 = document.getElementById("ddlAuthor");
let select2 = document.getElementById("ddlCountry");

var books = fetch("kitap.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(veri => {

    // Sets do not contain duplicates.
    let setOfAuthors = new Set();
    let setOfCountries = new Set();

    for (let data in veri) {
      for (deger of veri[data]) {
        table2.innerHTML += `
            <td><select><option value="${deger.author}"></select></td>
            <td><select><option value="${deger.country}"></select></td>
            <td><select><option value="${deger.imageLink}"></select></td>`
        setOfAuthors.add(deger.author);
        setOfCountries.add(deger.country);
      }

      // clear and fill <select> with <option>s.
      PopulateDDL(select1, setOfAuthors);
      PopulateDDL(select2, setOfCountries);
    }
  });

function populateDDL(ddl, setOfData) {
  let distinctSortedArray = Array.from(setOfData).sort();

  clearDDL(ddl);

  for (var i = 0; i < distinctSortedArray.length; i++)
    ddl.add(new Option(distinctSortedArray[i]));
}

function clearDDL(ddl) {
  while (ddl.options.length) {
    ddl.remove(0);
  }
}
```